# Handling Async Calls with Canvas and ForEach

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, canvas, asynchronous

I am trying to understand how I can utilize angular's $q library to display images which are based on a canvas drawing and then converted using `.toDataURL()`;

Basically I want to:

1. Loop over a images (`$scope.targetImages`)
2. Draw them on a canvas
3. Convert them to images using `.toDataURL()` and store it in (`$scope.outputImages`);
4. Display the images using ng-repeat

The problem is, that the function .toDataURL() can take some time before executed, thus resulting in a delayed call of step 4, and thus nothing being displayed.

I have tried the following, but it still resolves before all the images are converted.

As I have it now, when I call `drawCanvas`() for the second time, then the images are shown.

```
    // 1
    $scope.targetImages= {}

    drawCanvas().then(function(data){
      console.log("done: " + new Date())
      console.log(data)
      $scope.outputImages = data;
      $scope.previewMode = false; // switch views, display canvas, remove preview
    });


    function drawCanvas() {

    var defer = $q.defer();

    var targetImages = {} 
    angular.forEach($scope.targetImages , function(imageObj, key) {

      var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
      var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
      var img = new Image();
      img.src = imageObj.nativeURL;
      img.onload = start

      // 2
      function start() {

        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, img.width, img.height);

        outputImages[key] = {
          IID: key,
          dataURL: canvas.toDataURL()
        }

      } // start

    }); // for loop target images

    defer.resolve(outputImages);
    return defer.promise;

    } // draw canvas
```

And displayed as:

```
<img ng-show="!previewMode" ng-src="{{image.dataURL || ''}}" style="width: 100vw; max-width: 600px;">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, define a function that draws an image to the canvas and returns a promise for the result:

```
function drawToCanvas(nativeURL) {
    return $q(function (resolve) {
        var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
        var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        var img = new Image();

        img.src = nativeURL;
        img.onload = function () {
            ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, img.width, img.height);

            resolve(canvas.toDataURL());
        };
    });
}
```

The solution then becomes:

```
$scope.targetImages = [];

function drawCanvas() {
    // pResults is an array of promises
    var pResults = $scope.targetImages.map(function (imageObj) {
        return drawToCanvas(imageObj.nativeURL);
    });

    return $q.all(pResults);
}

drawCanvas().then(function(data) {
    // data is an array of imageUrls
    console.log("done: " + new Date())
    console.log(data)
    $scope.outputImages = data;
    $scope.previewMode = false; 
    // switch views, display canvas, remove preview
});
```

To simplify, I have changed `$scope.targetImages` and `$scope.outputImages` to be arrays instead of objects, but it shouldn't be too hard to go back to using objects for them if that's what you need.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, looking good. Am going to try it. Just a comment, where is the angular.forEach and does that change with resolve?

Comment: I've replaced the `angular.forEach` with an `Array#map` since that is the cleanest way to map one set of things to another set of things.

Comment: @JohnAndrews No, there's no need for a loop. `Array#map` takes care of the iteration.

Comment: But how does imageObj look like? Is it an an Object with just property .nativeUrl. Console.log(data) results in []

Comment: @JohnAndrews Yes, the assumption is that `$scope.targetImages` would be an array of objects with a `.nativeURL` property. In the code above, `$scope.targetImages` is initialized to an empty array, so you would need to put some values into it in order to get values out at the end.

Comment: Clear! Unfortunately it still does not appear in the screen... I tried $scope.targetImages = [{nativeURL: "img/california.jpg"}] and change ng-src to image (without .nativeUrl) and console.log(data) does give a return in the form of ["data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAASwA…XwrrDXZizfv/+OPD6/wEQtBv8MuJsHAAAAABJRU5ErkJggg=="]

Comment: @JohnAndrews Ok, well it looks like you're getting the values out at the end, so it's probably an issue of the way your view HTML is set up. Could you show me the `ng-repeat` part of your view that's for the images, and everything inside it?

Comment: Ah yes, I forgot to replace it to outputImages! However, now only a fraction of the image is displayed (top left corner).  <img ng-repeat="image in outputImages"
          ng-show="!previewMode"
          ng-src="{{image || ''}}" 
          style="width: 100vw; max-width: 600px;">

Comment: @JohnAndrews Not sure about that, but why do you have "`100vw`" for the width?

Comment: Wanted to fill it for 100% of the window. Removing it does not work either. Does it maybe pass the data too quickly in drawToCanvas, without actually having loaded it entirely? Cause in the canvas, it is also only draw partially.

Comment: @JohnAndrews How big is your canvas? Is it possible that the canvas is smaller than the images?

Comment: Adding var iw=canvas.width=img.width;var ih=canvas.height=img.height; inside drawToCanvas, results that the full canvas is displayed, but its a bit slow... Thanks for the help so far!